# jquery ui tabs and jquery plugins - plugin only being initialised once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am working on a site at the moment, that uses jquery ui tabs, in each tab I am implment jcarousel, it looks and works fine in the first tab, but when I switch to the second or the third tabs, there is no jcarousel functionality why is this? Here is my code,

```
`$("#related").tabs();`
`$('#complimentary-carousel, #similar-carousel, #viewed-carousel').jcarousel({
    scroll : 5,
    visible: 5
});`
```

The HTML looks like this,

```
<div id="related" class="clearfix">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#complimentary">Complimentary</a></li>
        <li><a href="#similar">Similar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#viewed">Recently Viewed</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="complimentary">
        <ul id="complimentary-carousel" class="carousel">
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;50</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;50</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;50</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;50</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;50</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;30</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;30</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;30</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;30</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;30</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="similar">
        <ul id="similar-carousel" class="carousel">
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;50</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;30</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="viewed">
        <ul id="viewed-carousel" class="carousel">
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;50</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;30</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;30</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;30</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;30</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="assets/img/products/mini-radio.png"/>
                    <span class="price">&euro;30</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See issue [here](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/434). It seems the only way to make it work is to initialize jcarousel on 'tabsshow' event. You will face problems with other plugins and widgets if you try to initialize them on hidden tabs.